# map: texture from new THREE.Texture(canvas) does not work

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

i want to use the texture from `new THREE.Texture(canvas)` to the PointsMaterial.
however, it does not work. the canvas is on the top right. but the `CubeGeometry` 
only has the white point.

```
    var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
    texture.needsUpdate = 1;
```

when i use the texture from `new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "snowflake5.png" )` it worked.

this is demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNezgM

Where was my fault?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is OK to add a live link, but please show the relevant code in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instantiate a texture from a canvas element using the following pattern, you must set the `needsUpdate` flag to `true`.

```
    var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Alternatively, you can use this pattern, and the `needsUpdate` flag will be set for you:

```
    var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( canvas );
```

Regarding your bug, your code does not work because:

```
true === 1 // false
```

three.js r.85